# Links in jQuery Mobile not working correctly in OperaMini

Tags: jquery, mobile, hyperlink, opera-mini

Problem is very simple - I have two links to the two different divs. I will show you my minimized prepared example:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-title="test: home" >
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2> Not correctly working links </h2>
        <a href="#test_111">link_test_111</a>
        <a href="#test_222">link_test_222</a>                
    </div>
</div>

<div id="test_111" data-role="page" >
    This is test_111 link page content
</div>

<div id="test_222" data-role="page" >
    This is test_222 link page content
</div>
```

If I clicked `<i>link_test_111</i>` I got of course content of div `id=test_111` and my url's tail is `/#test_111`. The same with *link_test_222* - I got div `id=test_222` and `/#test_222`.

And here is the problem, when I go to the test_111 and BACK do the home page and next click on the test_222 the page is crashed, to the home page div is loaded content of previous clicked div (there is no change in url (/.. - URLs tail of home page..) ).

It happens only in my OperaMini on Android. Another mobile browsers working correctly.

Comment: Do you have javascript click handlers for test_111/test_222 ?

Comment: No, but jQuery Mobile Framework dosen't need any handlers for that. It should be done automaticaly..

ps. Now I see that on jquery mobile official site with Demos this  problem EXIST too.